# Create HTML elements in loop

Tags: php, loops

Given a number like i.e: `6` I need to generate 6 `DIV` elements.
For example:

```
$number = 6;
// PHP generates the DIV for $number of times (6 in this case).
```

How can I do it? I am not an expert of PHP loops, if this is the case. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example uses of the different types of loops you could use. Hopefully you can see how they work.

## Foreach Loop

```
    $element = "<div></div>";
    $count = 6;
    foreach( range(1,$count) as $item){
        echo $element;
    }
```

## While Loop

```
   $element = "<div></div>";
   $count = 0;
   while($count < 6){
       $count++;
       echo $element;
   }
```

## Simple For Loop

```
$element = "<div></div>"; 
$count = 6;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function generateDIVs($number)
{
  for ($i = 0; $i <= $number; $i++)
  {
    echo "<div><div/>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to generate 6 div elements loop is necessary.

using while loop:

```
$count = 1;
while($count <= 6){
    $count++;
    echo "<div></div>";
}
```

using for loop:

```
$count = 6;
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo "<div></div>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
    echo "<div class=\"example\"></div>";
}
```

Note that IDs (the `#` part) have to be unique on a page, so you can't have 6 different divs with the same `#example` id.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples I use often, for quick mock-upping repeated HTML while working with PHP

### [`array_walk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)  with iteration index and range

```php
$range = range(0, 5);
array_walk($range, function($i) {
  echo "
  <section class='fooBar'>
    The $i content
  </section>
  ";
});
```

If **tired of escaping double quotes** `\"` or using `'` or *concatenation hell*, you could simply use **Heredoc**.

```
$html = function($i) {
echo <<<EOT
  <section class="fooBar">
    The $i content
  </section>
EOT;
};

array_map($html, range(1, 6));
```

The only small "disadvantage" of using [Heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) is that the closing `EOT;` cannot have leading and following spaces or tabs - which might look ugly in a well structured markup, so I often place my functions on top of the document, and use `<?php array_map($html, range(0, 5)) ?>` where needed.

### [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-repeat.php)  when an index is not needed

```
$html = "
  <section class='fooBar'>
    Some content
  </section>
";

echo str_repeat($html, 6);
```

Comment: If you aren't `return`ing inside the callback of `array_map()`, then you probably shouldn't be using `array_map()`.  In these instances, `array_walk()` is usually more appropriate since it doesn't expect anything to be returned.

Answer (score -1):

you need echo command. Basically you are generating html by printing a string. Example

```
echo '<div> </div>';
```

will generate 1 div. You need it 6 times. You might want to use loop as well, but this is too basic question and I gave you a start.