# Basic iteration for/loop 0 = 1?

Tags: php, for-loop, operators

This is going to be a stupid question I know, but for the life of me I cant find the answer and because help on for/loops is so common its a minefield. I got this basic loop from another question and I think its what I need, however, even if I set `generateDIVs(0);`
I still get one. I tried setting `$i` to -1 so the count would be correct but it didn't work.

Perhaps I'm being overly pedantic here but how do you get the right number to the right count. If I want 3 div's, I want to put 3, not 2.

Original question: [PHP generate DIVs based on a specific number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153637/php-generate-divs-based-on-a-specific-number)

```
    ​function generateDIVs($number)
    {
     for ($i = 0; $i <= $number; $i++)
     {
      echo "<div> Whoop <div/>";
     }
     echo "Number count:" .$number;
    }

generateDIVs(0);
```

Comment: `0 <= 0` is `true`...!

Comment: ps. I dont have enough reputation to comment on someone elses question which is why I had to create a new one. Sorry.

Comment: @deceze so I need to change <= to something else? sorry im a lowly noob :/

Comment: @ablueman yes you need to change <= to <

Comment: @ablueman voting your question up. should get you some rep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should look like this
The condition should match for `<` and not `<=`

```
function generateDIVs($number)
{
 for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)
 {
  echo "<div> Whoop <div/>";
 }
 echo "Number count:" .$number;
}

generateDIVs(0);
```

Comment: On the off chance this save me creating a different question. 

What do I need to look at to then +1 to the count?

Heres what I have so far: http://gw.ablueman.co.uk/generateDiv.php
So each tab is created by the loop script. Next step is to be able to add another. Can you just give me a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Change the <= to <

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to think about this logically, otherwise it can be confusing if you're not familiar with loops.

the `<=` operator means `less than OR equal to`, so while this statement is true, the loop will continue.

In your example you start the loop off on 0, as `$i = 0`

`for ($i = 0; $i <= $number; $i++)`

So the first time the loop runs, it will check if `$i` is `less than OR equal to` whatever value was stored in `$number`.

What value did you place in `$number`? Well taking a look `generateDIVs(0)` the value that you pass it is 0.

So the loop will run the first time, check if `$i` (which is 0) is `less than OR equal to` `$number` (which is 0).

Is 0 `less than OR equal to` 0? Yep, 0 = 0.

So the loop will run once, and then increment `$i` by 1. 1 is not `less than OR equal to` 0, so it will not run again.

If you change your statement to

`for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++)`

The loop will continue to run whilst `$i` `is less` than `$number`.

Passing it the same value you did before `generateDIVs(0)`, the loop will initially check if `$i` (currently 0) `is less` than 0. Which it isn't, so it will not run.

Pass it a different value such as  `generateDIVs(1)`, the loop will initially check if `$i` (currently 0) `is less` than 1. Which it is, the loop will run once, and then the value of `$i` increments.

The loop will then check if it can run again by checking if  `$i` (currently 1) `is less` than 1, which it isn't, so it doesn't run.

I'd recommend reading up about PHP's [Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). The internet may be a minefield of information, but the Official PHP Manual should always be one of the first things to check if you have an issue understanding something.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
function generateDiv( $number ) {

    $counter = $number
    while( $counter-- ) {
        echo '<div>Whoop</div>';
    }

    echo $number;
}
```